# Alpha transparency ignored when rendering

Tags: rendering, materials, transparency, lighting

How can I get alpha-transparent surfaces to actually behave transparent when rendered?

When I make a shape and set its material to one with alpha transparency:

[image: Base colour dialogue for the material on this shape.]

The Layout shows me the material is 70% transparent, as specified:

[image]

When rendered, though, that shape turns opaque:

[image]

Where do I need to change something so the shape and light behave as they do in the Layout workspace?

If it matters: this is Blender 3.0.1. I'm very new to using Blender and if there are settings or functions you name, I probably don't know where they are.

Comment: There's an "Alpha" socket on the Principled BSDF material (separate from the alpha channel in "Base Color"). Does that setting work for you?

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A material has a “Blend Mode” property.

By default, this was set to “Opaque”.

When I set the property to value “Alpha blend”, the surface is correct transparency in the rendered image.

Comment: Already had this, not the issue for me :(

Any other ideas?